# Creating a docx file in git bash

Tags: bash, git-bash

I have to create a large amount of docx files for work. I figured instead of doing it manually, I could use git bash and create all of them through a loop. I have pretty basic knowledge of it, so I hope I'm not asking something too stupid.

I just did a little test, running:

```
echo "Hi" > hi.docx
```

It created a file represented by a little Word icon, but I can't open it. Is there a way to create an actual docx file in bash that will just open as a blank Word document?

Comment: I believe the `.docx` format is actually some form of a compressed zip file, which is why it fails to open when created in the way you have specified (I don't see why Git is relevant with what you are trying to do either).

Comment: It's not relevant in any way, Git bash is just the only bash shell I have ever used so I figured I would use it again. Maybe I'll remove the single Git tag then. Do you have any idea what way I *could* create it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to create an actual docx file in bash that will just
>   open as a blank Word document?

No sure how to create word document in bash, but if you just want to create some blank word document, you can manually create an empty document, then copy it to different file names.

one example to copy empty word document to files as 1.docx 2.docx ... 9.docx

```
for i in {1..9}; do cp empty.docx $i.docx; done
```

Comment: That's pretty clever; think that'll be my solution for now. Thanks.

Comment: Just to add: This is almost same as how "Right click in empty space in folder window -> New -> microsoft word document" works in case of windows OS.